# Can the + button on a TFS kanban board be wired up to a Work Template?

Tags: tfs

TFS 2018 on-premise.

I have created a new Work Template for bugs from `/_admin/_work?type=Bug&_a=templates` which pre-populates a number of fields on a new bug when clicked-through via a URL posted elsewhere.

[image]

What I'd like to be able to do is create the new work item based on the template from the + button on the kanban board.

[image]

How do I bind that + > Bug link to my Work Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it's not able to do this.

> Q: How do I set a default template for a team?
>
> A: The feature to set a default template for a team isn't a supported
>   feature at this time.

You could only

- Adding a work item using a template is to open the template link
  within a browser window
- Apply a template to new or existing work item(s)

The `+` Bug will only open a Bug work item with default template. Then you could choose the template later.

More detail please kind refer our official doc here: [Use templates to add and update work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: Ok, that's what we've ended up doing; applying the template once the bug is created. Thanks Patrick.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks for your kindly response, If my reply helped. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer* which will also help others in the community. In case they get stuck with same situation in the future.